# linux script for loop

Tags: linux

I have a small question regarding for loops in linux bash scripts.

I have a folder that contains 10000 files. I wrote for loop to list 100 files from the 10000.

```
For a in ~/Desktop/folder/*.txt
Do

    Echo $a

Done
```

However, I need to list the biggest 100 files in the folder and not the first 100 files depending on alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using a for loop?  If you just want to  see the 100 biggest files, do:

```
ls -S | head -n 100
```

Comment: Just as an addon - if you want the filesizes as well you can do 

ls -Ss | head -n 100

Answer (score 0):

If you do the loop just to get the files, be aware that there is a tool for that: `ls`.

See the man page of ls for commands which suit your problem: `man ls`

To answer your question:

You can use the output of `ls -S`, which sorts the files by size to loop over:

```
ls -S *.txt | while read file; do 
    echo $file
done
```

To limit the amount of files, you can use `head`. The following example will give output you the first 100 lines from the output of `ls`.

```
ls *.txt | head -n 100
```